# Oracle Linux or Ubuntu Server as a hypervisor?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, distribution-choice, oracle

I own a HP Proliant DL380 Rack Server. I would like to use it as a hypervisor for a production environment. I was thiking of installing CentOS with KVM on it, but unfortunately CentOS is not realiable to use as a hypervisor since it got it's EOL aheaded.

Now I searched on the internet for an alternative and I found that Oracle has some kind of GNU / Linux distribution that has compatibility with RHEL-CentOS and that really looks rock-solid stable.

But in the other hand, I readed some comments talking about how bad Oracle usually treats Open Source software, which makes me a little bit uncomfortable.

My last alternative would be to install Ubuntu Server with KVM and start working.
Do you think Oracle Linux performance and support are really worth it to use it as a hypervisor ? Or should I just forget about it and start using Ubuntu Server ?

Comment: RHEL is free for up to 16 production servers now. That was part of the CentOS changes.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above.

Unless you have a very specific reason for choosing a RHEL-like system, I suggest you choose one of the purpose built hypervisor distributions - [Proxmox](https://www.proxmox.com/en/), [Unraid](https://www.unraid.net/) and [XCP-ng](https://xcp-ng.org/) being the obvious candidates. It'll be much less work to build and manage your environment and you'll end up with a tool designed for the job not one adapted to the job.